# .htaccess is NOT responding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create an `.htaccess` script for my site URL but it is not working...

I have a root (WAMP Server) folder where I have my site folder, `Folders` where I have the index.php. In it I also have folder `A`, `B`, and `C`.
Folder `A` has `abc.php` and it has a link, `<a href = 'http://localhost/Folders/B/users.php?user=name'>View User</a>`. I want my URL to show up 
like this: `http://localhost/Folders/B/name` but nothing is happening.

The `.htaccess` file is stored in `Folders`.

**Apache code:**

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /Folders/B/

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)$ /Folders/B/users.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should write your link as such. htaccess is not replacing it in your files.

Comment: Have you set AllowOverride to true in your vhost configuration?

Comment: @IanJamieson what's that and how is it set?

Comment: Don't worry, if the answer there is doing something for you then it means it is enabled. All this does is say to Apache that there might be an htaccess file within your project, and if so allow it to override the default Vhost settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /Folders/B/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /users\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This changing the `URL` as expected but the page is not loading. It shows `NOT Found` with `404 Not Found` as the title of the page.

Comment: What is the URL do you see in your browser after redirect? Is it `http://localhost/Folders/B/name` ?

Comment: ok can you try updated code now. Also tell me when you get 404 what exact error do you get in browser.

Comment: Have just tried it but it says **Not Found** `The requested URL /Folders/B/yax was not found on this server.`